# New to python making a reddit bot

Tags: python, discord, python-3.6, discord.py, reddit

I'm making a reddit discord bot and I don't know what I'm doing wrong

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import praw
reddit = praw.Reddit(client_id = "sda",
                     client_secret = "fdsf",
                     username = "aasdsa",
                     password = "password",
                     user_agent = "sd")

b = commands.Bot(command_prefix = ".p ")

@b.command()

async def meme(ctx):

    subreddit = reddit.subreddit("dankmemes")
    all_subs = []

    top = subreddit.top(limit = 10)

    for sumbission in top:
        all_subs.append(sumbission)

    random_sub = all_subs.choice()

    name = random_sub.title()
    url - random_sub.url()

    em = discord.Embed(title = name)
    
    em.set_image(url = url)

    await ctx.send(embed = em)
```

It's supposed to send a post from a subreddit whenever I type .p sub, what is wrong and why won't it work? I also tryed this in another .py file and the file won't open without closing immediately. Also, what do I type in user_agent? Here's my application if you need it: https://ibb.co/B64vrWM

```
import praw

reddit = praw.Reddit(client_id = "example",
                     client_secret = "example",
                     username = "Psychological_Win_55",
                     password = "not_my_real_password",
                     user_agent = "I don't know what I put here")

subreddit = reddit.subreddit("memes")
all_subs = []

top = subreddit.hot(limit=10)

for sumbission in subreddit.hot(limit=10):
    print(sumbission.title)
```

Comment: You didn't delete the password in the first code brackets, you should delete and reask your question with editing it.

Comment: @Nurqm if this happens, it's better to _change the password_ that was exposed instead of trying to hide the exposure. You never know who's already seen the question and made a note of the credentials

Comment: Editing answer is not the solution, they can see the edits. You should change your password and delete the question.

Comment: It's an alt its honestly fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out.

When I was telling python to pick a random submission, I needed to do

```
import random
```

and then do

```
random.choice(all_subs)
```

and not

```
random_sub = all_subs.choice()
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a root python issue to me, as you're claiming that python file in the lower codeblock does not even seem to run. It should either print the 10 submission titles (the praw syntax is correct), or throw some kind of error (either 403 or 404).

Since none of this is happening, I'm going to guess that you're perhaps new to Python, and I'll also guess that you're on Windows.

In this case, assuming praw is installed ([if not, install it with pip](https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started/installation.html)), I recommend going to Powershell (not python shell), and entering:

`python3 path/to/file.py`

(could be simply `python` instead of `python3` depending on your current configuration.

When you run that, you'll either get an error which will be helpful in debugging this, or you'll get 10 submission titles printed!

If any of my assumptions are wrong please let me know.